# Hangman Javascript - my code doesn't seem to be updating the word placeholder when a letter is guessed correctly

Tags: javascript, html, contentplaceholder

So my program prints the random word to the console so I can check what the word is for testing and implementation, so when I am testing the code and guessing correct correct letters the word place holder doesn't update after the guess button is clicked it just cycles through the stages of hangman. Here's my code for the program;

```
    var wordsArray = ["monitor", "program", "application", "keyboard", "javascript", "gaming", "network"];
var word;
var goesLeft;
var placeholder;
var input;
var wordLength;
var wordSubstring;
var currentWord;

  function newGame()
  {

    placeholder = "";
    goesLeft = 10;
    var word = wordsArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordsArray.length)];
    currentWord = 0;
    word = wordsArray[currentWord];
    wordLength = currentWord.length;
    wordSubstring = currentWord.substring;
    console.log(word);
    var myElement = document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = "Click to guess";
    var myPicElement = document.getElementById("hangimage").src = "http://fetlar.kingston.ac.uk/pp/hangman10.jpg";

    for (var count = 0; count < word.length; count++)
    {
      placeholder = placeholder + "-";
    }

    document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML = placeholder;
    document.getElementById("gamestatus").innerHTML = "Game running";
  }

  function guessLetter()
  {
    var correct = 0;

    var inputBox = document.getElementById("guessinput");
    input = inputBox.value;


    console.log(word);

    for (var count = 0; count < wordLength; count++)
    {
      if (input == word.substring(count, count + 1))
      {
        correct++;
        placeholder = placeholder.substring(0, count) + input + placeholder.substring(count + 1, placeholder.length + 1);
        document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML = placeholder;
      }
    }

    if (correct == 0)
    {
      goesLeft--;
    }
    var url = document.getElementById("hangimage").src = "http://fetlar.kingston.ac.uk/pp/hangman" + goesLeft + ".jpg";

    if (placeholder == word)
    {
      document.getElementById("hangimage").src = "http://fetlar.kingston.ac.uk/pp/hangman_win.jpg";
      alert("You guessed the word correctly. You win!");
    }

    if (goesLeft == 0)
    {
      alert("You lose");
      newGame();
    }
  }
newGame();
document.getElementById("button").onclick = guessLetter;
```

Here's my code for the placeholder where to problem must be underlying, the program also runs fine I do not get any errors.

```
 for (var count = 0; count < wordLength; count++)
{
  if (input == word.substring(count, count + 1))
  {
    correct++;
    placeholder = placeholder.substring(0, count) + input + placeholder.substring(count + 1, placeholder.length + 1);
    document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML = placeholder;
  }
}
```

Here's the HTML linked to the code;

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
   <h1>Hangman</h1>
   <img id="hangimage" src="http://fetlar.kingston.ac.uk/pp/hangman9.jpg" />
   <div id="placeholder" style="font-size: 1.5em; font-family: monotype; color: red;">-------</div>
   <div id="gamestatus">Game running</div>
   <input id="guessinput" type="text" size="1" />
   <button id="button">Click to guess</button>
   <br/>
   <div>Guessed Letters</div>
   <div id="guessedletters">(guessed letters will go here)</div>
</div>
```

If anyone could tell me what the problem is that would be great, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 problems here :

First of all, your word variable is global, so don't redefine it in your `newGame()` function

```
var word = wordsArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordsArray.length)];
```

should be

```
word = wordsArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordsArray.length)];
```

The second problem is here :

```
wordLength = currentWord.length;
```

should be

```
wordLength = word.length;
```

Here is an edited jsFiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/vj2rx/

Comment: Sorry I have come across one problem with this it's nothing to do with your edit but when I use the currentWord variable it eliminates the random word generator and just uses the 1st word of the array which is "monitor" yet when I take it out I have the original problem also? Cheers

Comment: Because this line makes no sense :word = wordsArray[currentWord]; you just got a word using a random() function, then you set up to word value to the first value of your array... Why would you do that ? Remove this line.

Comment: @OwenBrain Also I don't understand why you unchecked my answer.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to. I'll check it again

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, this is working code for you.

```
var wordsArray = ["monitor", "program", "application", "keyboard", "javascript", "gaming", "network"];
var word;
var goesLeft;
var placeholder;
var input;
var wordLength;
var currentWord;

  function newGame(){
     placeholder = "";
     goesLeft = 10;
     word = wordsArray[getRandom(0,wordsArray.length)];
     wordLength = word.length;
     console.log(word);
     var myElement = document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = "Click to guess";
     var myPicElement = document.getElementById("hangimage").src = "http://fetlar.kingston.ac.uk/pp/hangman10.jpg";

     for (var count = 0; count < word.length; count++)
     {
          placeholder = placeholder + "-";
     }

     document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML = placeholder;
     document.getElementById("gamestatus").innerHTML = "Game running";
  }
  function getRandom(min,max){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
  }
  function guessLetter()
  {
     var correct = 0;

     var inputBox = document.getElementById("guessinput");
     input = inputBox.value;


     for (var count = 0; count < wordLength; count++)
     {
       if (input == word.substring(count, count + 1))
       {
        correct++;
        placeholder = placeholder.substring(0, count) + input + placeholder.substring(count + 1, placeholder.length + 1);
        document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML = placeholder;
       }
    }

    if (correct == 0)
    {
      goesLeft--;
    }
    var url = document.getElementById("hangimage").src = "http://fetlar.kingston.ac.uk/pp/hangman" + goesLeft + ".jpg";

    if (placeholder == word)
    {
      document.getElementById("hangimage").src = "http://fetlar.kingston.ac.uk/pp/hangman_win.jpg";
      alert("You guessed the word correctly. You win!");
    }

    if (goesLeft == 0)
    {
      alert("You lose");
      newGame();
    }
  }
newGame();
document.getElementById("button").onclick = guessLetter;
```

I suggest you should make a class for this, it will be better.

Comment: As much as I appreciate you just giving me working code, I'd rather just like to know where I went wrong and how I can fix it as I don't learn anything, I'm in my 1st year at uni so I am really trying to understand everything, it also saves yourself some time haha, thanks anyway

Comment: ok i will edit your code and make comment besides it where you went wrong.

Comment: Oh sorry I probably didn't even mean too, but I have finished it now, many thanks for your help